# Disable Desktop Icon Text shadows

Tags: windows-11

The latest windows update (I installed 2023.09.27) caused my desktop icon text to have shadows. I recall this happening at various times in the past and a simple restart would clear them away.

Now I can not get rid of the shadows. I have tried all the ways that I can find through a google search. The "Visual Effects Performance Options" for drop shadows is unchecked, the registry HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced DWORD ListviewShadow is set to zero. I looked in group policy editor on the desktop, desktop and there is no longer a switch to disable the shadows.

Changed my desktop background to a darker gray and that makes the shadows less noticeable but they are still there.

Does anyone have a suggestion that I haven't tried? I am currently in the process of uninstalling today's updates, hoping that will clear them but don't know when I can install the updates in the future without a solution.

Comment: Did you even tried this? https://www.top-password.com/blog/remove-shadow-from-desktop-icon-text-in-windows-11/

Comment: @HarshNJ: It's anwered in the question.

Comment: Just asking, the update might had forced it then.

Answer (score 0):

> The latest windows [11] update ..... caused my desktop icon text to
> have shadows.

All my Windows 11 machines did this - Production and Insider after the most current update in the last 7 days.

The main setting to fix this (uncheck drop shadow in Advanced System Settings) has worked for decades.

Now Microsoft has (deliberately or otherwise) attempted to force drop shadow on all of us.

This issue is only true for the newest update to Windows 11 (in the current week from today). Windows 10 is still working correctly.

So you cannot fix this issue in any reasonable way because it is internally broken in Windows.

I have entered feedback in the Feedback Hub with a good screen shot depicting the issue. I encourage you to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons of this ugly effect is ... AltTab settings.
When it is set to 2 here:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer "AltTabSettings"=dword:00000002
```

you will get that effect.
To get rid of this change it to 0 or 1